# java method without "this" parameter on internal variable

Tags: java

I ran over some java code and i saw something i can't quite get it . 
Why does the code below work without puting `this` in front of `diameter`

```
class Shape {
    public double area ()
    {
        return 0;

    }
}


class Circle extends Shape {                  
    Circle (double diameter) {                  
        this.diameter = diameter;
    }
    private static final double PI = Math.PI;   
    private double diameter;                    

    public double area () {                     
        double radius = diameter / 2.0;  <-------- LOOK HERE
        return PI * radius * radius;
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape s1 = new Circle (2.5);
        System.out.println (s1.area());

    }
}
```

The code works perfect ... with or without `this.diameter/diameter`

Comment: You do not need `this` to access member variables of the same class.It is mostly used in reference to member variables to differentiate between member variables in and function arguments.

Comment: Man i use s1 = new ... what if i use s2 = new with different value for the diameter .. how does it know to which object does `diameter` belong to ?

Comment: A simple style guide: Use `this` when you are refering to object attributes or the object itself inside the object class.

Comment: Small point but don't take a deep copy of `PI`; there is no point in copying constants.

Comment: ...use `import static java.lang.Math.PI;` instead (following on from @Bathsheba's comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor `Circle(double diameter)`, the function parameter `diameter` is *shadowing* the field of the class.

Unless you tell it otherwise (by writing `this.diameter`), the compiler will assume you are referring to the function parameter **not** the field. Writing `this.foo = foo` in Java constructor code is idiomatic.

In your function `area()`, there is no such ambiguity: `this.diameter` and `diameter` *both* refer to the field.

Comment: i still dont understand, it should have been `this.diameter` enforced . I am talking only about `area() method` . Does java assume that if area() has no diameter parameter then it uses `this` pointer on it by default ?

Comment: @123onetwothree Yes. But if you are confused you better use always `this` to make you clear when you use an object attribute and when not.

Comment: I know that but i was curious why does java dont enforce programmers to put `this` where refering to current object

Comment: Because it would be a pain in the neck to have to write `this.` *every* time you were referring to a field.

Comment: aaaa, lol :) others languages enforce you too do that